# @OneToMany shows duplicate values for collection variable

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting filtered 'Trainer' entities, but collection (trainedMonkeys) is not filtered. 'trainedMonkeys' variable is holding all 'Monkey' objects instead of holding only the one with 'isThumb = true'.

Can someone please check if below criteria I am using is correct?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List&lt;Trainer&gt; listTrainers() {         
        Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Trainer.class)
        .createAlias("trainedMonkeys", "tm")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("tm.isThumb", true))
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Trainer.java

```
public class Trainer {  
    private Long trainerId;

    private String trainerName;

    public List&lt;Monkey&gt; trainedMonkeys;
```

Monkey.java

```
public class Monkey {

    private Long id;

    private String monkeyName;  

    private boolean isThumb;
```

I am executing below code in the controller,

```
for (Trainer trainer : trainerList){  
            System.err.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");  
            System.err.println("Trainer ID*****"+trainer.getTrainerId());  
            System.err.println("Trainer Name******"+trainer.getTrainerName());  
            monkeyList = trainer.getTrainedMonkeys();  
            for (Monkey monkey : monkeyList){  
                System.err.println("Monkey ID*****"+monkey.getId());  
                System.err.println("Monkey Name*****"+monkey.getMonkeyName());  
            }  
            System.err.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");  
        }
```

and the output is as below (Monkey_2 and Monkey_6 are the only objects that should be present as only they satisfy the criteria) please help,

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
Trainer ID*****88 
Trainer Name******TrainerSachin 
Monkey ID*****87 
Monkey Name*****Monkey_1 
Monkey ID*****88 
Monkey Name*****Monkey_2 
Monkey ID*****89 
Monkey Name*****Monkey_3 
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
Trainer ID*****89 
Trainer Name******TrainerVinod 
Monkey ID*****90 
Monkey Name*****Monkey_5 
Monkey ID*****91 
Monkey Name*****Monkey_6 
Monkey ID*****92 
Monkey Name*****Monkey_7 
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: Set hibernate.show_sql to true in your hibernate config and let's see what sql it is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should hold all. You misinterpret Criteria restrictions. Restrictionss filter which criterias returned entities should meet. They do not filter elements out from the collections in returned entities.

Query returning entity with subset of relations to related entities would make things complex. Think about what should happen when such an entity is merged back to database.

More details about subject can be found from [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria).

Comment: Does it mean that I can not achieve the desired result? I want my collection to hold only the elements that match the criteria as 'isThumb=true'.

Also query on the console looks just fine. It provides two rows when I execute it on SQL editor.

Comment: select this_.ID as ID4_1_, this_.trainer_name as trainer2_4_1_, trainedmon3_.trainer_id as trainer1_, tm1_.id as monkey2_, tm1_.id as id5_0_, tm1_.thumb as thumb5_0_, tm1_.monkey_name as monkey3_5_0_ from trainer this_ inner join TrainedMonkeys trainedmon3_ on this_.ID=trainedmon3_.trainer_id inner join monkey tm1_ on trainedmon3_.monkey_id=tm1_.id where tm1_.thumb=?

Comment: select trainedmon0_.trainer_id as trainer1_1_, trainedmon0_.monkey_id as monkey2_1_, monkey1_.id as id5_0_, monkey1_.thumb as thumb5_0_, monkey1_.monkey_name as monkey3_5_0_ from TrainedMonkeys trainedmon0_ left outer join monkey monkey1_ on trainedmon0_.monkey_id=monkey1_.id where trainedmon0_.trainer_id=?

Comment: Yes, approach in general is wrong. Queries are about choosing which entities are part of result. They are not tool to construct relations in entities that are part of result.